# AD replication: The target principal name is incorrect. 2146893022

Tags: active-directory, replication

I have three domain controlers, and repadmin /showrepl command outputs the following:

```
C:\Windows\system32>repadmin /showrepl

Repadmin: running command /showrepl against full DC localhost
Default-First-Site-Name\TSSVDC01
DSA Options: IS_GC DISABLE_OUTBOUND_REPL
Site Options: (none)
DSA object GUID: 3e556767-3e6a-434b-95df-f37620cb0ac4
DSA invocationID: 3e556767-3e6a-434b-95df-f37620cb0ac4

==== INBOUND NEIGHBORS ======================================

DC=domain,DC=lan
    Default-First-Site-Name\TPSVDC03 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: b8fe2d78-8454-4f2e-bb2d-39d7722320bc
        Last attempt @ 2019-08-05 12:56:58 failed, result -2146893022 (0x8009032
2):
            The target principal name is incorrect.
        54327 consecutive failure(s).
        Last success @ 2019-04-09 20:45:39.
    Default-First-Site-Name\TPSVDC01 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: 622c774b-51b4-43ca-899a-3e0df8dcb75f
        Last attempt @ 2019-08-05 13:07:09 failed, result 8456 (0x2108):
            The source server is currently rejecting replication requests.
        8 consecutive failure(s).
        Last success @ 2019-08-05 12:42:30.

CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=lan
    Default-First-Site-Name\TPSVDC01 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: 622c774b-51b4-43ca-899a-3e0df8dcb75f
        Last attempt @ 2019-08-05 12:56:58 failed, result 8456 (0x2108):
            The source server is currently rejecting replication requests.
        1 consecutive failure(s).
        Last success @ 2019-08-05 12:42:29.
    Default-First-Site-Name\TPSVDC03 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: b8fe2d78-8454-4f2e-bb2d-39d7722320bc
        Last attempt @ 2019-08-05 12:56:58 failed, result -2146893022 (0x8009032
2):
            The target principal name is incorrect.
        2750 consecutive failure(s).
        Last success @ 2019-04-09 19:53:08.

CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=lan
    Default-First-Site-Name\TPSVDC01 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: 622c774b-51b4-43ca-899a-3e0df8dcb75f
        Last attempt @ 2019-08-05 12:56:58 failed, result 8456 (0x2108):
            The source server is currently rejecting replication requests.
        1 consecutive failure(s).
        Last success @ 2019-08-05 12:42:29.
    Default-First-Site-Name\TPSVDC03 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: b8fe2d78-8454-4f2e-bb2d-39d7722320bc
        Last attempt @ 2019-08-05 12:56:58 failed, result -2146893022 (0x8009032
2):
            The target principal name is incorrect.
        2746 consecutive failure(s).
        Last success @ 2019-04-09 20:36:08.

DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=domain,DC=lan
    Default-First-Site-Name\TPSVDC03 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: b8fe2d78-8454-4f2e-bb2d-39d7722320bc
        Last attempt @ 2019-08-05 12:56:58 failed, result 1256 (0x4e8):
            The remote system is not available. For information about network tr
oubleshooting, see Windows Help.
        2752 consecutive failure(s).
        Last success @ 2019-04-09 19:53:08.
    Default-First-Site-Name\TPSVDC01 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: 622c774b-51b4-43ca-899a-3e0df8dcb75f
        Last attempt @ 2019-08-05 12:56:58 failed, result 8456 (0x2108):
            The source server is currently rejecting replication requests.
        1 consecutive failure(s).
        Last success @ 2019-08-05 12:42:31.

DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=domain,DC=lan
    Default-First-Site-Name\TPSVDC03 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: b8fe2d78-8454-4f2e-bb2d-39d7722320bc
        Last attempt @ 2019-08-05 12:56:58 failed, result 1256 (0x4e8):
            The remote system is not available. For information about network tr
oubleshooting, see Windows Help.
        5362 consecutive failure(s).
        Last success @ 2019-04-09 19:53:08.
    Default-First-Site-Name\TPSVDC01 via RPC
        DSA object GUID: 622c774b-51b4-43ca-899a-3e0df8dcb75f
        Last attempt @ 2019-08-05 12:56:58 failed, result 8456 (0x2108):
            The source server is currently rejecting replication requests.
        1 consecutive failure(s).
        Last success @ 2019-08-05 12:42:31.

Source: Default-First-Site-Name\TPSVDC03
******* 54327 CONSECUTIVE FAILURES since 2019-04-09 20:45:39
Last error: -2146893022 (0x80090322):
            The target principal name is incorrect.

Source: Default-First-Site-Name\TPSVDC01
******* 5 CONSECUTIVE FAILURES since 2019-08-05 12:42:31
Last error: 8456 (0x2108):
            The source server is currently rejecting replication requests.
```

I also tried the `repadmin /options <DC NAME> +DISABLE_OUTBOUND_REPL` but I get the same error.

I'm also adding dcdiag log from both servers:

```
Directory Server Diagnosis


Performing initial setup:

   Trying to find home server...

   Home Server = tssvdc01

   * Identified AD Forest. 
   Done gathering initial info.


Doing initial required tests


   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\TSSVDC01

      Starting test: Connectivity

         ......................... TSSVDC01 passed test Connectivity



Doing primary tests


   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\TSSVDC01

      Starting test: Advertising

         Warning: TSSVDC01 is not advertising as a time server.

         ......................... TSSVDC01 failed test Advertising

      Starting test: FrsEvent

         ......................... TSSVDC01 passed test FrsEvent

      Starting test: DFSREvent

         There are warning or error events within the last 24 hours after the

         SYSVOL has been shared.  Failing SYSVOL replication problems may cause

         Group Policy problems. 
         ......................... TSSVDC01 failed test DFSREvent

      Starting test: SysVolCheck

         ......................... TSSVDC01 passed test SysVolCheck

      Starting test: KccEvent

         ......................... TSSVDC01 passed test KccEvent

      Starting test: KnowsOfRoleHolders

         [TPSVDC03] DsBindWithSpnEx() failed with error -2146893022,

         The target principal name is incorrect..
         Warning: TPSVDC03 is the Schema Owner, but is not responding to DS RPC

         Bind.

         [TPSVDC03] LDAP bind failed with error 8341,

         A directory service error has occurred..
         Warning: TPSVDC03 is the Schema Owner, but is not responding to LDAP

         Bind.

         Warning: TPSVDC03 is the Domain Owner, but is not responding to DS RPC

         Bind.

         Warning: TPSVDC03 is the Domain Owner, but is not responding to LDAP

         Bind.

         Warning: TPSVDC03 is the PDC Owner, but is not responding to DS RPC

         Bind.

         Warning: TPSVDC03 is the PDC Owner, but is not responding to LDAP

         Bind.

         Warning: TPSVDC03 is the Rid Owner, but is not responding to DS RPC

         Bind.

         Warning: TPSVDC03 is the Rid Owner, but is not responding to LDAP

         Bind.

         Warning: TPSVDC03 is the Infrastructure Update Owner, but is not

         responding to DS RPC Bind.

         Warning: TPSVDC03 is the Infrastructure Update Owner, but is not

         responding to LDAP Bind.

         ......................... TSSVDC01 failed test KnowsOfRoleHolders

      Starting test: MachineAccount

         ......................... TSSVDC01 passed test MachineAccount

      Starting test: NCSecDesc

         ......................... TSSVDC01 passed test NCSecDesc

      Starting test: NetLogons

         ......................... TSSVDC01 passed test NetLogons

      Starting test: ObjectsReplicated

         ......................... TSSVDC01 passed test ObjectsReplicated

      Starting test: Replications

         [Replications Check,TSSVDC01] A recent replication attempt failed:

            From TPSVDC03 to TSSVDC01

            Naming Context: DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=domain,DC=lan

            The replication generated an error (1256):

            The remote system is not available. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help.



            The failure occurred at 2019-08-05 20:56:58.

            The last success occurred at 2019-04-09 19:53:08.

            5370 failures have occurred since the last success.

         [Replications Check,TSSVDC01] A recent replication attempt failed:

            From TPSVDC01 to TSSVDC01

            Naming Context: DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=domain,DC=lan

            The replication generated an error (8456):

            The source server is currently rejecting replication requests.

            The failure occurred at 2019-08-05 20:56:58.

            The last success occurred at 2019-08-05 12:42:31.

            10 failures have occurred since the last success.

            Replication has been explicitly disabled through the server

            options.

         [Replications Check,TSSVDC01] A recent replication attempt failed:

            From TPSVDC03 to TSSVDC01

            Naming Context: DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=domain,DC=lan

            The replication generated an error (1256):

            The remote system is not available. For information about network troubleshooting, see Windows Help.



            The failure occurred at 2019-08-05 20:56:58.

            The last success occurred at 2019-04-09 19:53:08.

            2760 failures have occurred since the last success.

         [Replications Check,TSSVDC01] A recent replication attempt failed:

            From TPSVDC01 to TSSVDC01

            Naming Context: DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=domain,DC=lan

            The replication generated an error (8456):

            The source server is currently rejecting replication requests.

            The failure occurred at 2019-08-05 20:56:58.

            The last success occurred at 2019-08-05 12:42:31.

            9 failures have occurred since the last success.

            Replication has been explicitly disabled through the server

            options.

         [Replications Check,TSSVDC01] A recent replication attempt failed:

            From TPSVDC01 to TSSVDC01

            Naming Context: CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=lan

            The replication generated an error (8456):

            The source server is currently rejecting replication requests.

            The failure occurred at 2019-08-05 20:56:58.

            The last success occurred at 2019-08-05 12:42:29.

            9 failures have occurred since the last success.

            Replication has been explicitly disabled through the server

            options.

         [Replications Check,TSSVDC01] A recent replication attempt failed:

            From TPSVDC03 to TSSVDC01

            Naming Context: CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=lan

            The replication generated an error (-2146893022):

            The target principal name is incorrect.

            The failure occurred at 2019-08-05 20:56:58.

            The last success occurred at 2019-04-09 20:36:08.

            2754 failures have occurred since the last success.

         [Replications Check,TSSVDC01] A recent replication attempt failed:

            From TPSVDC01 to TSSVDC01

            Naming Context: CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=lan

            The replication generated an error (8456):

            The source server is currently rejecting replication requests.

            The failure occurred at 2019-08-05 20:56:58.

            The last success occurred at 2019-08-05 12:42:29.

            10 failures have occurred since the last success.

            Replication has been explicitly disabled through the server

            options.

         [Replications Check,TSSVDC01] A recent replication attempt failed:

            From TPSVDC03 to TSSVDC01

            Naming Context: CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=lan

            The replication generated an error (-2146893022):

            The target principal name is incorrect.

            The failure occurred at 2019-08-05 21:38:23.

            The last success occurred at 2019-04-09 19:53:08.

            2761 failures have occurred since the last success.

         [Replications Check,TSSVDC01] A recent replication attempt failed:

            From TPSVDC03 to TSSVDC01

            Naming Context: DC=domain,DC=lan

            The replication generated an error (-2146893022):

            The target principal name is incorrect.

            The failure occurred at 2019-08-05 20:56:58.

            The last success occurred at 2019-04-09 20:45:39.

            54335 failures have occurred since the last success.

         [Replications Check,TSSVDC01] A recent replication attempt failed:

            From TPSVDC01 to TSSVDC01

            Naming Context: DC=domain,DC=lan

            The replication generated an error (8456):

            The source server is currently rejecting replication requests.

            The failure occurred at 2019-08-05 20:56:58.

            The last success occurred at 2019-08-05 12:42:30.

            90 failures have occurred since the last success.

            Replication has been explicitly disabled through the server

            options.

         ......................... TSSVDC01 failed test Replications

      Starting test: RidManager

         ......................... TSSVDC01 failed test RidManager

      Starting test: Services

         ......................... TSSVDC01 passed test Services
```

Server 2:

```
Directory Server Diagnosis


Performing initial setup:

   Trying to find home server...

   Home Server = TPSVDC03

   * Identified AD Forest. 
   Done gathering initial info.


Doing initial required tests


   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\TPSVDC03

      Starting test: Connectivity

         ......................... TPSVDC03 passed test Connectivity



Doing primary tests


   Testing server: Default-First-Site-Name\TPSVDC03

      Starting test: Advertising

         Warning: TPSVDC03 is not advertising as a time server.

         ......................... TPSVDC03 failed test Advertising

      Starting test: FrsEvent

         ......................... TPSVDC03 passed test FrsEvent

      Starting test: DFSREvent

         There are warning or error events within the last 24 hours after the

         SYSVOL has been shared.  Failing SYSVOL replication problems may cause

         Group Policy problems. 
         ......................... TPSVDC03 failed test DFSREvent

      Starting test: SysVolCheck

         ......................... TPSVDC03 passed test SysVolCheck

      Starting test: KccEvent

         ......................... TPSVDC03 passed test KccEvent

      Starting test: KnowsOfRoleHolders

         ......................... TPSVDC03 passed test KnowsOfRoleHolders

      Starting test: MachineAccount

         ......................... TPSVDC03 passed test MachineAccount

      Starting test: NCSecDesc

         ......................... TPSVDC03 passed test NCSecDesc

      Starting test: NetLogons

         ......................... TPSVDC03 passed test NetLogons

      Starting test: ObjectsReplicated

         ......................... TPSVDC03 passed test ObjectsReplicated

      Starting test: Replications

         [Replications Check,TPSVDC03] A recent replication attempt failed:

            From TPSVDC01 to TPSVDC03

            Naming Context: DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=domain,DC=lan

            The replication generated an error (8457):

            The destination server is currently rejecting replication requests.

            The failure occurred at 2019-08-05 20:48:57.

            The last success occurred at 2019-04-09 19:59:47.

            2915 failures have occurred since the last success.

            Replication has been explicitly disabled through the server

            options.

         [TPSVDC01] DsBindWithSpnEx() failed with error -2146893022,

         The target principal name is incorrect..
         [Replications Check,TPSVDC03] A recent replication attempt failed:

            From TSSVDC01 to TPSVDC03

            Naming Context: DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=domain,DC=lan

            The replication generated an error (8457):

            The destination server is currently rejecting replication requests.

            The failure occurred at 2019-08-05 20:48:57.

            The last success occurred at 2019-04-09 19:59:46.

            2969 failures have occurred since the last success.

            Replication has been explicitly disabled through the server

            options.

         REPLICATION LATENCY WARNING

         ERROR: Expected notification link is missing.

         Source TSSVDC01

         Replication of new changes along this path will be delayed.

         This problem should self-correct on the next periodic sync.

         [Replications Check,TPSVDC03] A recent replication attempt failed:

            From TSSVDC01 to TPSVDC03

            Naming Context: DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=domain,DC=lan

            The replication generated an error (8457):

            The destination server is currently rejecting replication requests.

            The failure occurred at 2019-08-05 20:48:57.

            The last success occurred at 2019-04-09 19:59:46.

            2825 failures have occurred since the last success.

            Replication has been explicitly disabled through the server

            options.

         REPLICATION LATENCY WARNING

         ERROR: Expected notification link is missing.

         Source TSSVDC01

         Replication of new changes along this path will be delayed.

         This problem should self-correct on the next periodic sync.

         [Replications Check,TPSVDC03] A recent replication attempt failed:

            From TPSVDC01 to TPSVDC03

            Naming Context: DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=domain,DC=lan

            The replication generated an error (8457):

            The destination server is currently rejecting replication requests.

            The failure occurred at 2019-08-05 20:48:57.

            The last success occurred at 2019-04-09 19:59:46.

            2825 failures have occurred since the last success.

            Replication has been explicitly disabled through the server

            options.

         [Replications Check,TPSVDC03] A recent replication attempt failed:

            From TSSVDC01 to TPSVDC03

            Naming Context: CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=lan

            The replication generated an error (8457):

            The destination server is currently rejecting replication requests.

            The failure occurred at 2019-08-05 20:48:57.

            The last success occurred at 2019-04-09 20:36:08.

            2825 failures have occurred since the last success.

            Replication has been explicitly disabled through the server

            options.

         [Replications Check,TPSVDC03] A recent replication attempt failed:

            From TPSVDC01 to TPSVDC03

            Naming Context: CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=lan

            The replication generated an error (8457):

            The destination server is currently rejecting replication requests.

            The failure occurred at 2019-08-05 20:48:57.

            The last success occurred at 2019-04-09 20:36:23.

            2825 failures have occurred since the last success.

            Replication has been explicitly disabled through the server

            options.

         [Replications Check,TPSVDC03] A recent replication attempt failed:

            From TPSVDC01 to TPSVDC03

            Naming Context: CN=Configuration,DC=domain,DC=lan

            The replication generated an error (8457):

            The destination server is currently rejecting replication requests.

            The failure occurred at 2019-08-05 20:48:57.

            The last success occurred at 2019-04-09 19:59:46.

            2856 failures have occurred since the last success.

            Replication has been explicitly disabled through the server

            options.

         REPLICATION LATENCY WARNING

         ERROR: Expected notification link is missing.

         Source TSSVDC01

         Replication of new changes along this path will be delayed.

         This problem should self-correct on the next periodic sync.

         [Replications Check,TPSVDC03] A recent replication attempt failed:

            From TPSVDC01 to TPSVDC03

            Naming Context: DC=domain,DC=lan

            The replication generated an error (8457):

            The destination server is currently rejecting replication requests.

            The failure occurred at 2019-08-05 20:48:57.

            The last success occurred at 2019-04-09 20:36:13.

            12293 failures have occurred since the last success.

            Replication has been explicitly disabled through the server

            options.

         [Replications Check,TPSVDC03] A recent replication attempt failed:

            From TSSVDC01 to TPSVDC03

            Naming Context: DC=domain,DC=lan

            The replication generated an error (8457):

            The destination server is currently rejecting replication requests.

            The failure occurred at 2019-08-05 20:48:57.

            The last success occurred at 2019-04-09 20:24:51.

            6733 failures have occurred since the last success.

            Replication has been explicitly disabled through the server

            options.

         REPLICATION LATENCY WARNING

         ERROR: Expected notification link is missing.

         Source TSSVDC01

         Replication of new changes along this path will be delayed.

         This problem should self-correct on the next periodic sync.

         ......................... TPSVDC03 failed test Replications

      Starting test: RidManager

         ......................... TPSVDC03 passed test RidManager

      Starting test: Services

            w32time Service is stopped on [TPSVDC03]

         ......................... TPSVDC03 failed test Services
```

Comment: Did you try to run `dcdiag` on controllers?

Comment: I have edited the question with attached dcdiag logs.

Comment: Looks like a network (firewall) or kerberos issue. Check if time on both servers match, if it's ok, I would try to reset machine password of a failing server via `netdom`.